# Google Cloud CLI Docker documentation is missing a Dockerfile from example

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently discovered Google Cloud CLI Docker image and I want to install some additional components using the example from documentation (link: [Installing the Google Cloud CLI Docker image # debian-based_images](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-docker#debian-based_images)).
The example tells me to execute `docker build` command with particular parameters but it does not say where to get the Dockerfile to build it.

Comment: That document seems to assume you already know how to write a Dockerfile. That being said, the example provided is a valid Dockerfile in itself.

Comment: Which image are you planning to use? Basically you would start your Dockerfile with the `FROM` statement, then add commands to modify that image. I am not sure in this case, but Google usually publishes everything on GitHub. Search on GitHub for their Docker repository.

Comment: @JohnHanley - found it. Thanks!

Comment: What did you find? Update your post with information.